# I get the error: intel is not defined

Tags: javascript, intel-xdk

This JavaScript line:

```
var imei= intel.xdk.device.uuid;
```

used to work on appFramework3 in  intel xdk.

I am now trying to use it in Framework7, but I always get the error: intel is not defined.

I am using App Designer in intel xdk 3619.

What can I do or check to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `intel.xdk.*` APIs were [deprecated](http://techterms.com/definition/deprecated) in late 2015 and were retired in early 2016. They continued to appear in the old Emulate tab, making it seem as if they were still supported.

However, the new Simulate tab does not support those retired APIs, thus the reason you are probably seeing that error. Likewise, Intel App Preview no longer supports them.

You can still include them in your app, by including the plugins (manually), but we advise against that since they have been retired and are not being maintained. We recommend you find an alternate API in the forum of a third-party Cordova plugin.